# Android screen Animation to both sides

Tags: android, animation

I can add animation while changing screen. The animation for ViewFlipper defined depending on what direction is chosen by user.
Is it ok to set animation a couple of times during runtime? I there any other solution to set different animation for screen depending on button chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it ok to set animation a couple of times during runtime.And u can also set different animation using a timer